# Why can't I emplace/insert into my map?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

This code fragment fails in VS 2015 (I don't have any other compilers to test it on):

```
class loader
{
bool parseMeta() const
{
    for (auto it = meta_.begin(); it != meta_.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::string line(*it);
        size_t n = line.find_first_of("=", 2);
        if (n == std::string::npos) { return false; }

        std::string key = line.substr(2, n);
        std::string value = line.substr(n + 1);
        kvp_.emplace(std::make_pair(key, value)); // <-- HERE
    }
    return true;
}

private:
    std::vector<std::string> meta_;

    std::map<std::string, std::string> kvp_;
};
```

Gives this lovely error:
`error C2662: 'std::pair<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,bool> std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::emplace<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>>(std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>> &&)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const std::map<std::string,std::string,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' to 'std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>> &`

However if I move `kvp_` to the line above the marked failure line (denoted by `<-- HERE`) then the error goes away.

Same with `insert`. I've tried making the `string`s `const` but that had not effect. Why is this occurring? What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method is marked as const, hence you cannot modify a member variable within its scope.

Change

```
bool parseMeta() const
```

to

```
bool parseMeta()
```

and it should compile.

Comment: That is correct.  I feel dumb for not realizing :-(

Comment: Theoretically, the `const` in the error message should have made this clear. Now if we could only figure out which of those "const"s is the one that makes it clear. ;)

Comment: I was focusing too much on the converting of `const map` to `_Tree`.